# Converting the some logic using java Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would Like to convert some logic using Java8 Stream. How should we modify the code?

```
public boolean isBFOrder(final BFReturn pReturnRequest) {
        ArrayList<BFReturnShip> shipGroupList =pReturnRequest.getShipGroupList();      
        Boolean bfOrder = false;
        for(BFReturnShip bfReturnShip : shipGroupList) {
            if(bfReturnShip.getModeOfReturn().equals(TYPE)) {
                bfOrder = true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return bfOrder;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
return pReturnRequest.getShipGroupList()
                     .stream()
                     .allMatch(i -> i.getModeOfReturn().equals(REFUND_ONLY));
```

Provided that `pReturnRequest.getShipGroupList()` is never `null`.

As @Holger points out, we can improve the piece above by covering the case where the list comes empty.

```
final List<BFReturnShip> list = pReturnRequest.getShipGroupList();
return !list.isEmpty() && 
    list.stream().allMatch(i -> i.getModeOfReturn().equals(REFUND_ONLY));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But getModeOfReturn() is the method of  BFReturnShip . That is something is not working. Would you suggest any changes here? @Andrew Tobilko

Comment: @rand it should work because `i` is an instance of `BFReturnShip` and we call `getModeOfReturn` on it

Comment: pReturnRequest.getShippingGroupList().stream()
                .allMatch(i -> ((BFReturnShip )i).getModeOfReturn().equals(.REFUND_ONLY));  I have done some changes .Need to cast to BFReturnShip.Now it'sworking. But Any ways, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @rand there is something wrong with `pReturnRequest.getShippingGroupList()` if you have to cast. Please, show the `getShipGroupList` signature

Comment: The original code would return `false` for an empty list.

Comment: @Holger is it a type of vacuous truth? Yes, I should have covered that...